# Size of ImageViews (with VectorDrawables) in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-vectordrawable

There is a dialog with a lot of vector images. How to calculate the size of each picture for any screen?

[image]

If i use

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ava_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

i get this result

[image]

But i need automatically set size for imageviews. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all VectorDrawables of the same maximum size in Vertical Scrolling RecyclerView, you need to install in xml at the root element

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I suppose for horizontal scrolling the values of the parameters should be reversed.